# Applying transforms to fastai v2 vision

Tags: fast-ai

In fastai v2 i am trying to add image augmentations

So

```
tfms = aug_transforms(do_flip = True,
                                 flip_vert=True, 
                                 max_lighting=0.1, 
                                 )
data = ImageDataLoaders.from_df(df,bs=5,item_tfms=tfms,folder=path_to_data)
```

this give output

`Could not do one pass in your dataloader, there is something wrong in it`

And when i do

```
data.show_batch()
```

it give

```
RuntimeError: "check_uniform_bounds" not implemented for 'Byte'
```

How to resolve

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue. It seems I can do padding and cropping, but anything more exotic raises the same error.

Comment: LOL no. Might be by up-voting we can bring answer to this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't try the do_flip transformation, but what worked for me was to apply them not as item_tfms but as batch_tfms:

```py
item_tfms = [ Resize((200, 150), method='squish')]
 
batch_tfms = [Brightness(max_lighting = 0.3, p = 0.4),
    Contrast(max_lighting = 0.6, p = 0.4),
    Saturation(max_lighting = 0.75, p = 0.4)]
 
db = DataBlock(blocks = (ImageBlock, CategoryBlock),
                  get_items = get_image_files,
                  splitter = RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42),
                  item_tfms=item_tfms,
                  batch_tfms=batch_tfms,
                  get_y = parent_label)
```

You can then feed the DataBlock into a DataLoader like in the [fastbook tutorial](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/02_production.ipynb)

Comment: *Smacks head* . Duh. Sometimes it's the simplest things.

Comment: @JudoWill And 
orozco got answer that can help us check it out

Answer (score 3):

I got this from fastai docs. Adding related to question stuff you can check everything [here](https://docs.fast.ai/tutorial.albumentations.html) Related to augs

```py
    class AlbumentationsTransform(RandTransform):
        "A transform handler for multiple `Albumentation` transforms"
        split_idx,order=None,2
        def __init__(self, train_aug, valid_aug): store_attr()
        
        def before_call(self, b, split_idx):
            self.idx = split_idx
        
        def encodes(self, img: PILImage):
            if self.idx == 0:
                aug_img = self.train_aug(image=np.array(img))['image']
            else:
                aug_img = self.valid_aug(image=np.array(img))['image']
            return PILImage.create(aug_img)
```

Basically this is all you need

For setting diff augs use

```py
    def get_train_aug(): return albumentations.Compose([
                albumentations.RandomResizedCrop(224,224),
                albumentations.Transpose(p=0.5),
    ])
    
    def get_valid_aug(): return albumentations.Compose([
        albumentations.CenterCrop(224,224, p=1.),
        albumentations.Resize(224,224)
    ], p=1.)
```

And then

```py
    item_tfms = [Resize(256), AlbumentationsTransform(get_train_aug(), get_valid_aug())]

    dls = ImageDataLoaders.from_name_func(
        path, get_image_files(path), valid_pct=0.2, seed=42,
        label_func=is_cat, item_tfms=item_tfms)
    dls.train.show_batch(max_n=4)
```

Enjoy